# Use mutex or mutex pointer in Golang?

Tags: go, pointers, mutex

I have a code snippet:

```
type calculation struct{
    sum int
    mutex sync.Mutex
}

func dosomething(c *calculation , wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    c.mutex.Lock()
    c.sum++
    c.mutex.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    c := new(calculation)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i:=0; i<10000000; i++{
        wg.Add(1)
        go dosomething(c, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(c.sum)
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
}
```

But I found that use a mutex pointer works too:

```
type calculation struct{
    sum int
    mutex *sync.Mutex
}

func dosomething(c *calculation , wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    c.mutex.Lock()
    c.sum++
    c.mutex.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    c := &calculation{0, new(sync.Mutex)}
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i:=0; i<10000000; i++{
        wg.Add(1)
        go dosomething(c, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(c.sum)
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
}
```

I made some tests on these 2 versions and found that there elapsed times are close.

So which one should I use? And Why should I use a mutex or mutex pointer? Are they have performance differences?

Comment: Well, according to the [sync docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/), "[v]alues containing the types defined in this package should not be copied.". But you're not copying it here, because `c` is a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Go `sync.Mutex` cannot be copied, so you would use a pointer to a (shared, non-copied) `sync.Mutex` when you have a data structure that can be copied sensibly but that has some portion of itself that is shared and *cannot* be copied sensibly, and you plan to pass it around by value and/or return it, so that it gets copied.

For instance:

```
type Thingy struct {
    notShared int
    mtx *Sync.mutex
    shared *int
}

func (t Thingy) Thingy {
    t.notShared += 3
    t.mtx.Lock()
    *t.shared *= 2
    t.mtx.Unlock()
    return t
}
```

(It would probably be more typical to have multiple non-shared fields, and then one pointer to a `struct` that contains both the mutex itself and the shared fields.  The above is mainly for illustration)

Given that your `calculation` structure is itself always passed around as a pointer, though, there's no reason to add a level of indirection to your example.

Edit: you added a question about performance differences.  Adding an extra (otherwise-unnecessary) indirection often costs a bit in performance, but in general, you should just write the *most readable* code you can first, and then measure it for performance issues.  Adding an extra unnecessary indirection tends to make the code slightly less readable, in my view, so here, performance and readability go together.

Comment: Thank you torek.  The "write the most readable code" help me alot.  A mutex here is only used by an instance of struct, lock/unlock.  Obviously I don't want anyone else to modify lock status. So a mutex pointer(shared) here is meaningless. But I think a mutex pointer here is legal too, the main difference might be store a mutex literal + pointer to mutex or store a mutex pointer（not sure about that after few days searching about the memory structure of struct in go）, so I think there is no such kind of  "extra indirection cost" here,  still need more efforts to explore it.

Comment: @Artisan: Go is a pretty simple language. If you declare something as `*T`, for some type `T`, Go will use a pointer to `T`. This means that access to the object requires an indirection, through the pointer. Go will sometimes be able to optimize away some indirections, but in general this adds work. The cost of following a pointer is usually quite tiny, but the cost of having a pointer in the first place can be larger, as it means more work for the garbage collector.

Comment: In general, it's worth paying this cost if: (a) we *must* have the pointer because we need to modify the (shared) object, or (b) we gain a big savings elsewhere. Otherwise it's merely a cost: maybe tiny, but eventually it might add up to something.

Comment: Ohhh! I should treat type struct T as a whole, if type T is accessed by *T, then T.mtx value is also found. If mutex field of T was declared as *mutex, extra cost arise. Thanks!